# Customized ConsoleAppender in Eclipse RCP gives circular dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, log4j, eclipse-rcp, fragment

I'm working on a Eclipse RCP application, and I would like to have a customized ConsoleAppender, so I can redirect all logs to the log window.
The log4j plugin and the log4j fragment (containing the log4j.properties) creates a unit which I manage to use successfully.
I've also created an 'extension' plugin containing my code to capture the log-data. Behold the 2 plugins and the fragment below.

```
rcp_external_log4j (plugin containing the jar file)
  log4j-1.2.16.jar

rcp_external_log4j_fragment (containing the log4j.properties file)
  log4j.properties (which points to VirtualConsol)

rcp_external_log4j_extension (plugin containing the VirtualConsol)
  src/VirtualControl.java (which extends ConsoleAppender)
```

When I execute my project from within the Eclipse debug environment everything works fine. The VirtualConsole forwards all logging data as expected.

However, when I try to export the project with the 'Eclipse product export wizard' to a standalone executable I get the following problem:

```
Problem Occured
'Export Product' has encountered a problem.
A cycle was detected when generating the classpath
rcp_external_log4j_extension
rcp_external_log4j
rcp_external_log4j_extension
```

The VirtualConsole extends ConsoleAppender and is also called from other parts of the code. 
The VirtualConsole is located in rcp_external_log4j_extension and uses log4j due to the extending of ConsoleAppender. 
The rcp_external_log4j uses the rcp_external_log4j_extension, due to that the rcp_external_log4j plugin is bundled with the  rcp_external_log4j_fragment, which refers to the VirtualConsole in the log4j.properties file.

Question: How can I write my own ConsoleAppender without getting a circular dependency? Can I put the code in the fragment? Can I put the code in the plugin containing the jar file (rcp_external_log4j)? I've tried those 2 attempts but without success...

Grateful for any help

---

Problem solved. src is put in the same plugin as the jar file.

```
rcp_external_log4j (plugin containing the jar file)
  log4j-1.2.16.jar
  src/VirtualControl.java (which extends ConsoleAppender)

rcp_external_log4j_fragment (containing the log4j.properties file)
  log4j.properties (which points to VirtualConsol)
```

and 'src' added to the classpath of rcp_external_log4j. Seen in the MANIFEST.MF as

```
Bundle-ClassPath: log4j-1.2.16.jar,
 src/
```

This way the VirtualConsole may be used both from the fragment and from the other code.

And the build.properties should contain:

```
jars.compile.order = src/
source.src/ = src/
output.src/ = bin/
```

for the code to be included in the exported product.

Comment: Could Dynamic-ImportPackage or Buddy Classloading, solve the circular dependency problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `rcp_external_log4j_fragment` needs to have `rcp_external_log4j_extension` in its build path, only in the manifest. This should remove the cycle.

Comment: I tried your solution, and managed to get rid of the cyclic dependency when exporting the product, however now the export fails due to that rcp_external_log4j_extension cant be found... thanks anyway.